# Xcode 8 Quick Help Not Working

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have **Xcode 8.2.1** and have the Documentation installed (Preferences/Components/Documentation), but the **Quick Help inspector** and **Option + Click** both show "No Quick Help" and a button to "Search Documentation".  I even tried in Terminal **-defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable** but I received *Domain (com.apple.dt.Xcode) not found.
Defaults have not been changed.*  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it by deleting Xcode 8 from Applications, all items in ~/Library/Developer and the com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist file in /Library/Preferences.  I then rebooted, emptied the Trash, downloaded and installed Xcode from the App store.  I think this problem was a result of upgrading to Xcode 8 over Xcode 7, but not completely sure.  Anyway, Quick Help works now and I can search the documentation when before it was stuck on "Loading".

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this several times when upgrading Xcode and have made it a practice to remove the old version before installing the new.  Great job and tutorial!

Comment: Thanks Jim for the kind words.